# Django accessing Model with property decorator

Tags: python, django

How do I access the data in the method with the property decorator. I can access it in the shell, and it is what I need, but it comes up blank in my site.

Models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    others = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    closed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def updates(self):
        updates = []
        categories = set(self.update_set.all().values_list(
            'category__id', flat=True))
        for cat_id in categories:
            updates.append(Update.objects.filter(
                project=self, category__id=cat_id).order_by('added').last())
        return updates

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Views.py:

```
class ProjectView(ListView):

    template_name = 'project_portal/home.html'
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
```

And I am trying to use the following in my template:

```
<div class="box5">
  {% for item in object_list %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.updates }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

So far the box is blank. However, I have managed to get this data in the Django shell with the following:

```
p = Project.objects.all()[0]
p.updates
```

This returns the correct data in the right order for the first project. What do I need to do to get it to appear in the site?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your problem is that you are using `.values()` in your queryset in your view. This will give you a list. The reason why it works in the shell is because you are working with model objects, and hence you are able to get the `updates` property. So remove `.values()` from `queryset = Project.objects.all().values()`

Read up more about `.values()` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, I've just edited my post to reflect both replies, and I get something now, but still not quite what I am after. Now I am finally getting some data through, however, I am getting the correct updates for one project as a list wrapped with square brackets and "<>" all in one field where just one of the updates should be, then the second line where the next update should be is all the updates from the second project and so on. This is then repeated for all project boxes. I hope that's understandable.

Comment: Just to try and clarify, I'm trying to get a scrolling page of boxes, one project per box, each box has a bit that shows the latest updates from each of 7 categories. It will ultimately show a snapshot of each project that our team is currently working on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the template has a var named `project`?  Try changing `project` for `object_list` or override the `get_context_data` method to pass project to the template.

Edit: After reading your edited question I think you want to do something like this.

```html
<div class="box5">
  {% for project in object_list %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      {% for category_update in project.updates %}
        <td>{{ category_update }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </table>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

If you keep watching the category update in a wrong way please share with us your Category Model.

Answer (score 0):

So this is now solved. The Models.py and Views.py in the original post are correct now, what was causing the rest of the issue was the Template, here is a short version of what was needed:

```
{% block home %}
   {% if object_list %}
   {% for project in project_list %}

   <div class="box1">
     <h4>{{ project.title }}</h4>
     <p>Project Status</p>
     <div class="square"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="box5">
     {% for item in project.updates %}
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>{{ item }}</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

The point I am making here is that there are two loops, one loops through projects in the object_list, and the second loop loops through items within the project.updates, which is fed by the method with the property decorator. I hope this is clear if anyone finds this looking for help.